# React components totaly exposed in production

Tags: reactjs, gulp

I have a problem in my Node/React app. All my react components are visible in the browser dev tools in production environment. Is there a way to prevent this ?

The react project is a ceative-tim's theme project and it's using gulp without cra nor webpack

Note : I'm already including this in the build command :

```
"build": "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-scripts build"
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? All Javascript code is always visible to users

Comment: Even in production, all the code is shown. Is there a way to minimise the js exposed?